# differential form of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

My textbook introduces the differential form of a differential equation with this example.

I know dy is a function of dx and x. dy(dx,x)=(dy/dx)(dx).

But how are the two equations equivalent? The second equation does not imply the first one when dx is zero.

And what is the point of having this form?

Comment: $dx$ is never zero. It's not even really a number. "Multiplying by $dx$" is just a (miraculously) handy mnemonic for a transformation that is actually pretty advanced.

Comment: @Arthur My textbook refers to "dx" and "dy" as differentials. And according to Wikipedia and my other calculus textbook, dy and dx are variables called differentials,     and dy = (the first derivative of a function at x ) times dx; the value of dy is used to approximate the change in the output of a function using the change in the first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

When $dx$ and $dy$ are [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) the equation
$$
(x^2+y^2)\,dx+6xy\,dy=0
$$
says that along every (not necessarily closed) curve in $\mathbb R^2$ the integral of the vector field
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}x^2+y^2\\ 6xy\end{matrix}\right)
$$
must be zero. This means: if the curve is
$$
\gamma:t\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}\gamma_1(t)\\ \gamma_2(t)\end{matrix}\right)\,,~~t\in[0,T]
$$
then
$$
\int_\gamma (x^2+y^2)\,dx+6xy\,dy=
\int_0^T (\gamma_1^2(t)+\gamma_2^2(t))\dot\gamma_1(t)+6\gamma_1(t)\gamma_2(t)\dot\gamma_2(t)\,dt
$$
must be zero. In particular, if the curve is
$$
\gamma:t\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}t\\ \gamma_2(t)\end{matrix}\right)\,,~~t\in[0,T]
$$
then
$$\tag{1}
\int_\gamma (x^2+y^2)\,dx+6xy\,dy=
\int_0^T t^2+\gamma_2^2(t)+6\,t\,\gamma_2(t)\,\dot\gamma_2(t)\,dt
$$
must be zero. Because this holds for every $T\ge 0$ it follows that the integrand on the RHS must be zero. When we change notation this is nothing else than the ordinary differential equation
$$\tag{2}
x^2+y^2+6xy\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$
we started with.

Conversely, using the same formalism it is easy to see that if $y$ is a solution of the ODE (2) then the line integral (1) is zero along every curve. This is another way of saying that the differential form $(x^2+y^2)\,dx+6xy\,dy$ must be zero.